The issue of using Read-Only List Properties in FXML
I am studying the official FXML documentation and have encountered some issues.
public class FxmlTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    private MyPoint point;
    @FXML void initialize(){
        System.out.println("items:" + point.getChildren());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("FxmlTest.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

FxmlTest.fxml
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="club.xiaojiawei.test.FxmlTest"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400">
    <fx:define>
        <MyPoint fx:id="point">
            <children>
                <String fx:value="B"/>
                <String fx:value="A"/>
                <String fx:value="C"/>
            </children>
        </MyPoint>
    </fx:define>
</AnchorPane>

@DefaultProperty("children")
public class MyPoint{

    private final ObservableList<String> children = FXCollections.observableList(new LinkedList<>());

    public ObservableList<String> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }


    private  int x;

    private  int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        System.out.println("setx");
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
        System.out.println("sety");
    }

    public MyPoint(@NamedArg("x") int x, @NamedArg("y") int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}


When defining a custom parameterized constructor, the print result is items:[B].
When I comment out the custom parameterized constructor and use the default constructor instead, the print result is items: [B, A, C].
Why does the constructor affect the values of the children?

@jewelsea Yes, I don't have a no-argument constructor, nor did I use any of the three methods. JavaFX obviously called the MyPoint(@NamedArg("x") int x, @NamedArg("y") int y) constructor to create the object, and at that time, my children property only contained one String element. However, when I remove that constructor, leaving only the implicit no-argument constructor in my MyPoint class, my children property contains the full set of three String elements.

@jewelsea The FXML documentation states: "As each sub-element of the  element is read, it is added to the list returned by Group#getChildren()". My MyPoint class is written in the same way, but why is the result different?

Replaced comments with an answer.  I know it isn't the answer you are looking for, but the info is better in an answer than in comments.

This definitely looks like a bug, though I wouldn't really expect the code, as posted, to "succeed". I'd expect this to throw an exception, since the FXML asks the FXMLLoader to instantiate MyPoint but doesn't provide parameter values for the only constructor. However, if you modify it so it does provide x and y values, or even just add in a second no-arg constructor, then you still see the behavior you describe. It seems like somehow the constructor parameters are consuming two of the values intended for the list. If you need this setup, the best workaround may be to create a builder.

The three ways mentioned in the fxml documentation for initializing an object without a default (I read that to mean no-argument) constructor are:

fx:value -> "a type that does not have a default constructor but provides a static valueOf(String) method"
fx:factory -> "The value of the attribute is the name of a static, no-arg factory method for producing class instances"
Builders -> "delegates object construction to a mutable helper class".

You don't seem to do any of those.
To be fair, the FXML documentation leaves much to be desired . . .

The FXML documentation states: "As each sub-element of the  element is read, it is added to the list returned by Group#getChildren()". My MyPoint class is written in the same way, but why is the result different?

Probably because you are using an undocumented @NamedArg annotation.
Perhaps the FXMLLoader thinks that all it needs to do to create your MyPoint object is invoke the constructor with the named arguments and nothing else. As the constructor isn't initializing the children, neither is the loader.
But that is just speculation on my part.  Because it is not documented anywhere, you would need to debug the FXMLLoader if you wanted to see what it does differently for a default constructor vs the named arg constructor, and the behavior could be subject to change without notice because undocumented behavior does not form part of the public API.
Additionally, your MyPoint class is not the same as the Group class. If you look at the Group implementation, it does not use @NamedArg and it has a default no-arg constructor, so comparing your implementation to Group is a false comparison.

I have debugged the code of the FXMLLoader class, and it correctly reads all my String elements internally, but when it finally converts, it only takes the first element.

@XiaoJiawei process for submitting a bug or feature request, or see the github repository or openjfx-dev mailing list to discuss or submit a patch.
